# SharePoint 2016 - Issue deploying solution

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, visual-web-part

So, our company is using SharePoint 2016 on premise and previously I have deployed a few custom solutions to it before and they work correctly.

Now however, I am trying to create/deploy a visual web part solution (farm solution only). Visual studio deploys the solution without errors but as soon as I open the site, it just gets stuck on "working on it". As soon as I retract the solution, it loads up just fine.

Any staring points on what I can do would be much appreciated.
So far I have tried creating several different solutions, viewing the uls logs (nothing seems out of the ordinary).

Comment: Check ULS log for detailed error information, C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you can do but i would start this way.

1. Retract the Solution from Farm
2. Recycle timer services on all server(s) in the farm
3. now make sure solution is completely removed from farm ( check from central admin > system settings > manage farm solution's)
4. Now Move the uptodate .wsp file to the SharePoint app server.
5. [Add the solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/add-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps) to farm using the `Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath pathofsolution.wsp`
6. Now [install the solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/install-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps) using the powershell `Install-SPSolution -Identity SolutionName.wsp -GACDeployment`
7. Activate the feature if it is required
8. Now check the status from Central admin, make sure it says deployed to all server(s).
9. Test the application.

If Still seeing the error:
 - Enable the Verbose logging and reproduce the error and analyze the logs.
 - May be need to peform the debugging of your solution.

I would test in dev / test farm.